# How to read data from relational database in apache flink streaming

Tags: java, streaming, apache-flink, flink-streaming

How we can read data from relational database using **custom data source**. I am new to flink streaming. I am facing problem while adding new custom data-source. So please help me to **add custom data source** and **read data** continuously from source DB.

Comment: pulling directly from relational database doesn't do streaming, though you can still do it like a batch process. Do you have a message queuing like Kafka or Kinesis you can pull data from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by Chengzhi, relational databases are not designed to be processed in a streaming fashion and it would be better to use Kafka, Kinesis or some other system for that.

However you could write a custom source function that uses a JDBC connection to fetch the data. It would have to continuously query the DB for any new data. The issue here is that you need a way to determine which data you have already read/processed and which you did not. From the top of my head you could use a couple of things, like remembering what was the last processed primary key, and use it in subsequent query like:

`SELECT * FROM events  WHERE event_id > $last_processed_event_id;`

Alternatively you could clear the `events` table inside some transaction like:

`SELECT * FROM unprocessed_events;
DELETE FROM unprocessed_events WHERE event_id IN $PROCESSED_EVENT_IDS;`

`event_id` can be anything that lets you uniquely identify the records, maybe it could be some timestamp or a set of fields.

Another thing to consider is that you would have to manually take care of checkpointing (of the `last_processed_even_id` offset) if you want to provide any reasonable `at-least-once` or `exactly-once` guarantees.